# Правильная загрузка текста в WKWebView

Tags: html, ios, swift, webview

Я использую этот код для загрузки моего html файла с текстом в `WKWebView`:

```
do {
   guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "\(readBookNumber)", ofType: "html")
       else { 
           print ("File reading error")
           return
       }
   var content =  try String(contentsOfFile: filePath, encoding: .utf8)
   let baseUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
            
   content.changeHtmlStyle(font: "Iowan-Old-Style", fontSize:  UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "textSize"), fontColor: textColor)
   webView.loadHTMLString(headerString+content, baseURL: baseUrl)
}
catch {
    print ("File HTML error")
}
```

и этот код для загрузки страницы, на которой пользователь остановил чтение в последний раз:

```
self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset.x = CGFloat(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "pageToLoad"))
```

Я использую код для загрузки последней страницы в этом методе:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
         self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset.x = CGFloat(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "pageToLoad"))
    }
}
```

Сначала я использовал `deadline: .now() + 0.1`, но это не сработало. Потому что изначально была загружена последняя прочитанная страница, и через несколько секунд я вижу что этот текст пересколчил на первую страницу. Я меняю `deadline: .now() + 0.5` и текст загружается нормально с последней прочитанной страницы. У меня было 700 страниц. Но теперь я хочу загрузить другой текст на 1700 страниц. И у меня такая же проблема, как и в первый раз. Я могу изменить `deadline: .now() + 1.0` и мой текст загрузится нормально. Но я думаю, что это не лучшее решение. Сейчас запускаю приложение на своем iPhone X. Но, возможно, если запущу его на iPad mini 2, мне стоит изменить `deadline: .now() + 10.0` или что-то в этом смысле потому что iPad mini 2 не очень мощный. Как решить проблему?

Comment: Залейте куда-нибудь тестовый проект с примером файла на 1700 страниц,  я посмотрю

Comment: @schmidt9 https://gofile.io/d/4wzUhA Запускайте на устройстве потому что на симуляторе может показаться, что все хорошо, но это не так. Я тестил на iPhone X и мне хватило задержки в 2 секунды. Сначала появляется первая страница, а потом уже та, на которой остановились в последний раз. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте решение с определением `contentSize`, изменение которого будет означать, что файл загрузился, поскольку на момент вызова метода `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)` размер контента внутри `webView.scrollView` еще равен нулю, поэтому листать некуда.

Мы добавляем 2 переменные

```
private var contentSizeObservationToken: NSKeyValueObservation!
private var isLoading = true
```

И затем используем наблюдение при инициализации веб вью

```
        contentSizeObservationToken = webView.scrollView.observe(\.contentSize, options: .new) {scrollView, _ in
            if self.isLoading {
                self.isLoading = false
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    scrollView.contentOffset.x = CGFloat(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "pageToLoad"))
                }
            }
        }
```

Также добавляем метод

```
    deinit {
        contentSizeObservationToken.invalidate()
    }
```

Для справки [обсуждение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660051/wkwebview-notification-when-view-is-actually-shown) вопроса с определением загрузки WKWebView

Comment: Мне вот это точно помогло - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64633612/14207208 Пока не знаю лучше Ваше решение использовать или по ссылке. Не сравнивал. Но Ваш и по ссылке ответы примерно одинаковы?

Comment: @User по ссылке для доступа к contentSize используется так называемый method swizzling (подмена метода), не лучшее решение имхо, тем более если можно решить это через наблюдение (KVO), но суть та же самая